# multiple custom directive in single page angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

i am new in angular.js

custom directive applabel.js

```
app.directive('applabel', function(service, languageData) {

  return {
    templateurl: 'label.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      'key': '@',
      'default': '@'
    },

    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

      var data = [{
        key: Id,
        value: "ID"
      }, {
        key: name,
        value: "Name"
      }, {
        key: sts,
        value: "status"
      }];

      if (languageData.length == '0') {
        service.getData().then(function(result) {
          languageData = result.data;
          var keyVal = scope.key;

          for (var i = 0; i < languageData.length; i++) {
            if (keyVal = languageData.length[i].key) {
              scope.value = languageData.length[i].value;
            } else {
              scope.value = scope.default;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

In languageData there is array like data.
i used multiple time this directive in my html page

my html page is

```
<applabel key="name" default="Default Name">

</applabel>

<applabel key="Id" default="id">

</applabel>

<applabel key="sts" default="STATUS">

</applabel>
```

label.html

```
<label>{{value}}</label>
```

when my html page is rendered applabel directive is called but its execution cycle is something different.
every time my service getData method is called but server side api doesn't called.
only last time my server side api called and value will be replaced. so i am little bit confused about that it is a correct execution cycle or not?

what i want that 1st time server side api called and result is assigned in languageData after than its length is not equal to '0' so that services and server side api was not called. and languageData is my .constant variable so that its value is not changed.

i want this type of execution cycle is there any way to achieve this??

Comment: It's hard to understand your code even with your explanation. Can you explain more on what it does and what is your expectation?

Comment: according to my code 'applabel' directive is called 3 times and when directive is called at 3rd time that time my server side api is called and assign value in languageData but my expectation is server side api is called at 1st time of directive execution and that time languageData value should set  according to service response.

Comment: Will you be able to include the source code for the languageData service?

Comment: I think you cannot assume the directives will be called in the same sequence they are declared. If you need specific sequence you should do that in your outer controller/service instead.